# How to get recognition (e.g. in Google Scholar) from all the citations to my website

Tags: citations, google-scholar, website

If you search my website (https://example.com) at Google Scholar, you get 400+ results. There are dozens of papers that mention my website because it shows valuable and concise data about thousands of plant and animal species.

The papers cite my website with the main URL (https://example.com) or some specific URL (https://example.com/item/macaca-silenius).

**Can I make my Google Scholar profile show that my website has been mentioned by 400+ papers?**

I have already created a profile at Google Scholar with the name of my website and with a verified email at my domain.

Comment: Did you consider publishing a scientific paper that describes your website?

Comment: Since your goal is larger than a simple web page provided from a leading company abusing its dominant position, I would suggest excluding their product from your question. Because your goal is just to get recognition, not to use a certain product.
Plus, google Scholar does not certify anything. It's just a collection of information available on other publishers sites...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably not possible. Google Scholar doesn't mention anything about citations to web pages on their [citations page](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/citations.html#citations). Like Louic suggested in the comments, if you want this recognition is could be worthwhile to publish a paper on your data set and try to have people reference that from now on. But that will unfortunately not retroactively fix this. You can show the citation count on your website if you feel so inclined.

Remember that you do already get recognition by people actually citing your website. I do not think many people value citation counts of a website on Google Scholar.

Comment: Good answer (+1). One might further add that Google Scholar explicitly mentions that they "provide a simple way for authors to showcase their academic publications" ([source](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/citations.html)). A website does not fall under the usual definition of "academic publication".

Comment: @lighthousekeeper elsevier.com is a website, nature.com is a website, mdpi.com is a website. I think it's settled that academic publishing is done almost exclusively through websites these days.

Comment: @Andrei obviously elsevier.com is a website for publications, but nobody cites 'elsevier.com' when you cite an article that is published in an Elsevier journal, you cite the specific publication. That's different from what the OP has, where the website is (basically) just a big data set. Here the website is much more the publication.

Comment: @Jeroen That's actually not true. The website is not what it's published. The data on the website is published, and I am assuming that OP had some contributions to that data in some way. I don't think that all those citations would not exist, if all those authors would have access to the same data OP colected, but not from a website. The website is most certainly not the publication.

Comment: @Andrei - There is a big difference between a big publisher (Elsevier) and OPs website. Nobody would cite 'elsevier.com', but people do cite OPs 'whatever.com' as a website. I did not say that the website is the publication, but it is in nature much more a publication than the website of a publisher. Anyway - this is a technical discussion that doesn't add to the answer so let's not continue to much.

Comment: @Andrei But OP wants to have the citations of his websites recognized by GS. Since a website is not an academic publication, it is not in the scope of GS. GS also does not collect citations of elsevier.com.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are getting recognition, that's what citations are. There isn't much other recognition that you can get on top of that.

Nevertheless, there are ways to increase the visibility of the recognition you already have. You should create a Google Scholar account with your own name. It wasn't the website that did the work, it was you. Then it would help if you would provide clear instructions on your website as to how should your work be cited. Unfortunately, there isn't a lot you can do to change how others cited you already, but at least you won't have this problem for the future.

Publishing your work in a peer reviewed journal is not necessary to get citations, although it makes it easier by fitting into the norms of academia. Contrary to other suggestions, your work is already published on whatever.com and it doesn't need a republishing on a different website (e.g. nature.com) for it to be considered published.

Comment: Andrei, the other answers/comments are not suggesting that the work is not yet published. They are suggesting they are not published *in a paper* specifically, which would give the opportunity for a Google Scholar citation count.

Comment: @Jeroen The difference is of course the stamp of approval added by peer-review.